# How to translate inline javascript?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, inline-scripting, django-translated-fields

So I'm working on a django project and we're having English translated to Czech (not important). I can do fine with regular tags being translated with `{% trans 'sample text' %}`

However, I have a button inside a link and on click, this link returns a confirmation. The full html looks like this

```
<a href="{% url 'foo' %}" onclick="return confirm(
       'Sample text')">
   <button>
       {% trans 'Regular trans tag' %}
  </button>
</a>
```

Now I would like to somehow translate the 'Sample text' text inside the confirm, however when I try it with `{% trans %}` it gives me error that 'foo/bar expected (js)'

Comment: Can you change your question to include what you’ve tried and also show the exact error you’re getting?

Answer (score 0):

Translate "Sample text" inside the JS:

```
<a href="{% url 'foo' %}" onclick="return confirm('{% trans "Sample text" %}')">
   <button>
       {% trans 'Regular trans tag' %}
  </button>
</a>
```

Or there are other options, if you need all the languages to be available on the client at runtime. Do you need this?